# Causing a subview to scroll with its superview

Tags: nsview, addsubview, nsscrollview, pdfview, pdfpage

Had to cover a subclass of PDFView with an NSView to draw lines and texts, as PDFPage or PDFAnnotation don't seem to work at all.
Successfully added the subview, showed a random text, but the problem is when I tried to scroll, only the underlining PDFView is scrolling, its subview (NSView) is standing still.
Codes are as following: (m_markingView is NSView, m_drawing is PDFView)

```
m_markingView = [[CLMarkingView alloc] initWithFrame:m_drawing.bounds];
[m_drawing addSubview:m_markingView];
[m_drawing setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

Anyone has any idea? Many thanks!
(PS: PDFPage and PDFAnnotation work only at the start of the page, when you scroll the PDFView, all the lines and annotations will go away without ever coming back.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I draw something on a PDF in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370101/how-do-i-draw-something-on-a-pdf-in-swift)

Comment: Similar but his method is excessively time consuming, I need something happens in real time, can't afford redraw the whole page constantly. Thank you for your kind advice, it did help in some way, at least broadened my thoughts.

Comment: If you don't mind a hacky solution then inspect the runtime view hierarchy of the `PDFView` and insert your view where you want.